# my guessing game counter keeps rising

Tags: java

so for class I'm supposed to make a guessing game that gives you clues as you get closer to the answer.  My question is when i run it and i get one Number correct, I would obviously keep that number and keep going with the other 4 numbers, when I do that, the problem is my correct digits counter keeps rising even if I don't get other digits correct.. how would I remedy this?  Would i be able to add breaks in each of the if statements or would that completely exit me out of my do while loop?

```
public class GuessingGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int guess,numDigitsCorrect=0,sumDigitsCorrect=0,attempts=0,answer;
    Random rng = new Random();
    Scanner consoleScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    answer = rng.nextInt(90000) + 10000;
    System.out.println("I have randomly chosen a 5-digit code for you to guess.Each time you guess,\n"
            +   "I will tell you how many digits are correct and the sum of the digits that are correct."
            +   "For example, if the number is \"68420\" and you guess 12468, I will respond:\n"
            +   "Number of Digits Correct: 1\n"
            +   "Sum of Digits Correct: 4\n"
            +   "From deduction, you will know the 4 was correct in the guess."
            +   "\nNow its your turn..................................................................");
    do{
        System.out.print("Please enter a 5-digit code (your guess): ");
        guess = consoleScanner.nextInt();
        int g1 = guess/10000;
        int g2 = guess%10000/1000;
        int g3 = guess % 10000 % 1000 / 100;
        int g4 = guess % 10000 % 100 /10;
        int g5 = guess % 10000 % 10 / 1;
        int a1 = answer/10000;
        int a2 = answer%10000/1000;
        int a3 = answer % 10000 % 1000 / 100;
        int a4 = answer % 10000 / 100 / 10;
        int a5 = answer % 10000 % 10 / 10;
        if(g1 == a1)
        {
            numDigitsCorrect ++;
            sumDigitsCorrect += a1;
            System.out.println("\nNumber of digits correct: " + numDigitsCorrect) ;
            System.out.println("Sum of digits correct: " + sumDigitsCorrect);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if(g2 == a2)
        {
            numDigitsCorrect ++;
            sumDigitsCorrect += a2;
            System.out.println("Number of digits correct: " + numDigitsCorrect) ;
            System.out.println("Sum of digits correct: " + sumDigitsCorrect);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if (g3 == a3)
        {
            numDigitsCorrect ++;
            sumDigitsCorrect += a3;
            System.out.println("Number of digits correct: " + numDigitsCorrect) ;
            System.out.println("Sum of digits correct: " + sumDigitsCorrect);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if (g4 == a4)
        {
            numDigitsCorrect ++;
            sumDigitsCorrect += a4;
            System.out.println("Number of digits correct: " + numDigitsCorrect) ;
            System.out.println("Sum of digits correct: " + sumDigitsCorrect);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if (g5 == a5)
        {
            numDigitsCorrect ++;
            sumDigitsCorrect += a5;
            System.out.println("Number of digits correct: " + numDigitsCorrect) ;
            System.out.println("Sum of digits correct: " + sumDigitsCorrect);
            System.out.println();
        }
        if(guess == answer)
        {
            System.out.println("****HOORAY!  You solved it.  You are so smart****");
            break;
        }
    }while (guess != answer);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to fix -

1. Make sure your `a4`, `a5` are correct

   ```
   int a4 = answer % 10000 % 100 / 10; // note the modulus

   int a5 = answer % 10000 % 10; // note divided by 1 or remove the redundant statement
   ```
2. Move your print statement out of your `if` block to the end of all if inside the `do` block as -

   ```
   if (g1 == a1) {
           numDigitsCorrect++;
           sumDigitsCorrect += a1;
   }
   ... //other if statements
   if (guess == answer) {
       System.out.println("****HOORAY!  You solved it.  You are so smart****");
       break;
   }
   System.out.println("Number of digits correct: " + numDigitsCorrect);
   System.out.println("Sum of digits correct: " + sumDigitsCorrect);
   ```
3. Also since you already do a check

   ```
   if (guess == answer) {
       System.out.println("****HOORAY!  You solved it.  You are so smart****");
       break;
   }
   ```

   within your `do` you can change your while condition to `true` as -

   ```
   do {
    ... your existing code
    } while(true);
   ```
4. To answer

> Would i be able to add breaks in each of the if statements

If you do so, for even a single digit match your loop will exit(break).

5. Importantly to fix the counter, initialize the counter within the do block as

   ```
   do {
       numDigitsCorrect = 0;
       sumDigitsCorrect = 0;
   .. // existing logic
   }
   ```

Comment: oh, i feel like a dummy lol thanks ! im super new at this still and just trying to hold all this information in..

Comment: @NamDuong welcome, if that resolves your problem do mark an answer.

Comment: btw why would you want to change the condition to true?  while what's true?
wouldnt it be easier to understand if i put the if (guess == answer ) on the outside of the do while loop?

Comment: @NamDuong it would be good to read, but the logical operation is already taken care by the break. A better way to do this would be to move just the block within `if (guess == answer )` outside the do..while. Just the block statement because the execution would come out of the loop in that case only when the condition is met and so checking again would be redundant.

Comment: i've moved my print statements out of the if statements but inside the do..while loop but the counter keeps going up for the sum of digits counter still

Comment: the counter would increment for each correct digit, which should be fine. For   e.g if your answer is 67890 and your guess is 67891 the counter should be `4` and sum should be `30`.

Comment: eg if the answer is 67890 and i guess 67891 you're right the counter should be at 4 and sum be at 30 but if i put in the same number my sum counter goes up and so does my digits counter still.. I'm playing with it right now and my correct digit counter is at 30 lol

Comment: ex.Please enter a 5-digit code (your guess): 77890
Number of digits correct: 3
Sum of digits correct: 22
Please enter a 5-digit code (your guess): 77892
Number of digits correct: 6
Sum of digits correct: 44
Please enter a 5-digit code (your guess):

Comment: @NamDuong yeah, you need to initialise the value of sum and numOfDigit at the start of the do,,while loop.

Comment: i have it initialized outside of the do..while loop, how would that effect it? wouldn't it still start at 0 ?

Comment: no, it wouldn't. Just try a dry run. Considering your above example.
Assume the answer is 77812
*Please enter a 5-digit code (your guess): 77890 Number of digits correct: 3 Sum of digits correct: 22 
Please enter a 5-digit code (your guess): 77892 Number of digits correct: 6 Sum of digits correct: 44* (though this time again the number of digits correct were 3, and sum was 22, but it started of form numOfDigit =3, sum =22 from the previous loop) and hence numOfDigit = 6 (3+3) and sum = 44(22+22)

Comment: hm thats weird.. how come if i initialize outside of the do while it keeps the counter going up, but inside it doesnt?

Comment: @NamDuong Just that inside it, the counter would be *reset* every time.

Comment: oh i see thanks alot for being so patient and explaining everything !